# localNotification.soundName from cache

Tags: ios, caching, nsbundle, localnotification

is it possible to assign a soundname for localNotification from the device cache?
I've tried to assign an existing file from the application bundle and it worked properly.

My app will record a soundfile what should work as localNotification.soundName. I can't save this file within the application bundle and so I want to use the soundfile stored in the cache.

Could someone help me?

Thanks,
Julian

Answer (score 0):

No. the docs say in multiple places that local notification sounds and push notification sounds have to be included with the binary bundle. [[Source]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)